# How to Continue R.raw.audio sound after completing one loop by clicking on button in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, audio

my program is working only once but i want to continue play sound every time, i have 98 audios, when i click on button and  1,2,3,.....97, 98 it's playing well but after 98,1,2,3 it's not playing sound in second loop. How to continue it's sound on next loop? your help will be appreciated. Thanks
my Code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private ImageView hImageViewPic;
private Button iButton, gButton;
MediaPlayer ourSong;

private int currentImage = 0;
private int currentAudio = 0;

int[] images = { R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2, R.drawable.p3,
        R.drawable.p4, R.drawable.p5, R.drawable.p6, R.drawable.p7,
        R.drawable.p8, R.drawable.p9, R.drawable.p10, R.drawable.p11,
        R.drawable.p12, R.drawable.p13, R.drawable.p14, R.drawable.p15,
        R.drawable.p16, R.drawable.p17, R.drawable.p18, R.drawable.p19,
        R.drawable.p20, R.drawable.p21, R.drawable.p22, R.drawable.p23,
        R.drawable.p24, R.drawable.p25, R.drawable.p26, R.drawable.p27,
        R.drawable.p28, R.drawable.p29, R.drawable.p30, R.drawable.p31,
        R.drawable.p32, R.drawable.p33, R.drawable.p34, R.drawable.p35,
        R.drawable.p36, R.drawable.p37, R.drawable.p38, R.drawable.p39,
        R.drawable.p40, R.drawable.p41, R.drawable.p42, R.drawable.p43,
        R.drawable.p44, R.drawable.p45, R.drawable.p46, R.drawable.p47,
        R.drawable.p48, R.drawable.p49, R.drawable.p50, R.drawable.p51,
        R.drawable.p52, R.drawable.p53, R.drawable.p54, R.drawable.p55,
        R.drawable.p56, R.drawable.p57, R.drawable.p58, R.drawable.p59,
        R.drawable.p60, R.drawable.p61, R.drawable.p62, R.drawable.p63,
        R.drawable.p64, R.drawable.p65, R.drawable.p66, R.drawable.p67,
        R.drawable.p68, R.drawable.p69, R.drawable.p70, R.drawable.p71,
        R.drawable.p72, R.drawable.p73, R.drawable.p74, R.drawable.p75,
        R.drawable.p76, R.drawable.p77, R.drawable.p78, R.drawable.p79,
        R.drawable.p80, R.drawable.p81, R.drawable.p82, R.drawable.p83,
        R.drawable.p84, R.drawable.p85, R.drawable.p86, R.drawable.p87,
        R.drawable.p88, R.drawable.p89, R.drawable.p90, R.drawable.p91,
        R.drawable.p92, R.drawable.p93, R.drawable.p94, R.drawable.p95,
        R.drawable.p96, R.drawable.p97, R.drawable.p98, R.drawable.p99 };

int[] audios = {R.raw.a0 ,R.raw.a1, R.raw.a2, R.raw.a3, R.raw.a4, R.raw.a5,
        R.raw.a6, R.raw.a7, R.raw.a8, R.raw.a9, R.raw.a10, R.raw.a11,
        R.raw.a12, R.raw.a13, R.raw.a14, R.raw.a15, R.raw.a16, R.raw.a17,
        R.raw.a18, R.raw.a19, R.raw.a20, R.raw.a21, R.raw.a22, R.raw.a23,
        R.raw.a24, R.raw.a25, R.raw.a26, R.raw.a27, R.raw.a28, R.raw.a29,
        R.raw.a30, R.raw.a31, R.raw.a32, R.raw.a33, R.raw.a34, R.raw.a35,
        R.raw.a36, R.raw.a37, R.raw.a38, R.raw.a39, R.raw.a40, R.raw.a41,
        R.raw.a42, R.raw.a43, R.raw.a44, R.raw.a45, R.raw.a46, R.raw.a47,
        R.raw.a48, R.raw.a49, R.raw.a50, R.raw.a51, R.raw.a52, R.raw.a53,
        R.raw.a54, R.raw.a55, R.raw.a56, R.raw.a57, R.raw.a58, R.raw.a59,
        R.raw.a60, R.raw.a61, R.raw.a62, R.raw.a63, R.raw.a64, R.raw.a65,
        R.raw.a66, R.raw.a67, R.raw.a68, R.raw.a69, R.raw.a70, R.raw.a71,
        R.raw.a72, R.raw.a73, R.raw.a74, R.raw.a75, R.raw.a76, R.raw.a77,
        R.raw.a78, R.raw.a79, R.raw.a80, R.raw.a81, R.raw.a82, R.raw.a83,
        R.raw.a84, R.raw.a85, R.raw.a86, R.raw.a87, R.raw.a88, R.raw.a89,
        R.raw.a90, R.raw.a91, R.raw.a92, R.raw.a93, R.raw.a94, R.raw.a95,
        R.raw.a96, R.raw.a97, R.raw.a98 };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hImageViewPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
    iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIleri);
    gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGeri);
    // Just set one Click listener for the image

    iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener);
    gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);

}


View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // Increase Counter to move to next Image and Audio
            currentImage++;
            currentAudio++;


            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

            hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

            ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,audios[currentAudio]);


            ourSong.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

};


View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // Decrease Counter to move to previous Image and Audio
            currentImage--;
            currentAudio--;

            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

            hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

            ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, audios[currentAudio]);

            ourSong.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
};
```

}

Comment: Prakash: Where i put these lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing rollover for currentAudio.

```
currentAudio = ++currentAudio % audios.length;
 AND
currentAudio = (--currentAudio + audios.length) % audios.length;
```